# Placing a widget in a column gives RenderIndexedStack object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: dart, flutter

I am placing the following in column like this

```
   Widget _getDropDownCombo()
    {
       Widget combo =  new DropdownButton(
            value: _currentItem,
               items:_dropDownMenuItems,
            onChanged: _changedDropDownItem
            );
       return Flexible(child:combo);
    }
```

and  `_getDropDownCombo` is being called from a row somewhere like this

```
child: new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                        _getDropDownCombo(),
                        getIcon(),
                    ],)
```

This gives me the error
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
flutter: RenderIndexedStack object was given an infinite size during layout.
flutter: This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
flutter: inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
flutter: The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is:
flutter:   RenderFlex#dfcbf relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
```

Why am I getting this error with DropDownButton ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Their might be problem because of the items inside your DropdownButton.
I've tried using this in items and it works just fine:

```
items: ['Foo', 'Bar'].map((String value) {
                    return new DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: value,
                      child: new Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
```

Comment: I've updated the answer please take a look. And if the issue continues then please update the info about your items inside the DropdownButton in your question, so i can understand your problem better and can give you better answer.